# AFNetworking Uploading Files in Background

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I need to be able to upload multiple video files and have it continue working when the app becomes inactive (home button pressed, etc...)  Here is the code I am using, but this pauses the uploads when I leave the app and resumes when I come back:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
for(ClipForUpload *clip in items){
    NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%i.mov", clip.media_link_guid, self.onClip]];
    NSUserDefaults *fetchDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *busToken = [fetchDefaults objectForKey:@"ActiveBusiness"];
    NSString *userToken = [fetchDefaults objectForKey:@"UserToken"];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@", userToken];

    //now put the video
    NSString *partUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.com/%@/media/stockfootage/%@/", busToken, clip.token];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"PUT" URLString:partUrl parameters:@{} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] name:@"media_file" error:nil];
    } error:nil];
    [req setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [req setTimeoutInterval:12000];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *oper = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
    [oper setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        float pct = ((float)totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100;
        pct = roundf(pct);
        NSLog(@"%f", pct);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.view];
            hud.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploading Clip %i of %i - %g%%", self.onClip + 1, (int)items.count, pct];
        });
    }];
    [mutableOperations addObject:oper];
}

NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    self.onClip++;
    NSLog(@"DONE WITH A CLIP");
} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");

}];
NSOperationQueue* operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Is there a way to modify this code so that the uploads will continue instead of pausing?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4

Comment: The above commented method only seems to allow me 3 minutes before it will terminate the app, if the user is uploading several files, that will not be enough!'